# Infinite loop -- sql query in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Basically, I'm trying to make a function to take entries in a database by gender, and put it into an array that's used to display a table. However, somewhere in the code below, I think I'm running into an infinite loop-- when I call the function, the page loads the right entries, but keeps loading, and the scrollbar gets longer and longer. I'm very new to php/mysql/web development in general, so any help would be much appreciated!

```
<?
function getbyGender($g, &$form_data){
$sql = "select * from user_info where gender='".$g."'";
echo $sql;
$query = mysqli_query($this->dblink, $sql) or die (mysql_error());


while($info = mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC))
{

  foreach($info as $key=>$value)
  {
      $form_data[$i][$key] = $value;
  }

  $i++;
}
} ?>
```

Code that displays the table (using the yuitable API):

```
//Array to store all column labels to be used
$fields = array(
    'uname'=>'Username',
    'flname'=>'Full Name',
    'bday'=>'Birthday',
    'gender'=>'Gender',
    'comments'=>'Comments',
    'email'=>'Email',
);

$columns4 = $fields;
$t_columns4 = array();

//Format the table
foreach($columns4 as $key=>$value)
{
    $t_columns4[$key]['key'] = $value;
    $t_columns4[$key]['label'] = $value;
    $t_columns4[$key]['sortable'] = "false";
    $t_columns4[$key]['className'] = '';
    if ($value == 'Comments')
    {
        $t_columns4[$key]['width'] = '200';
    }
    else{


      $t_columns4[$key]['width'] = '100';

    }
}



$form_data = array();
$urls4 = array();
$sort4 = array();
$form_table = new yuitable("formtable");
$form_table->setColumns($t_columns4);



$local_mysql->getByGender('f', $form_data);
```

Comment: So where are you defining `$i`?

Comment: you dont print in your function, so this method dont cause direct the long scrollbar. you should give us the code where you print the array

Comment: This doesn't actually print anything out, so if you got an infinite loop, the scrollbar wouldn't be getting any longer. If there's an issue, it's elsewhere.

Comment: Also - you're calling `mysql_error()`, but the rest of your functions are the `mysqli_` ones.

Comment: Oh. Wow. I somehow neglected to define $i. That was the issue, though I changed mysql to mysqli in all the instances in the code afterward.

Comment: Your inner foreach() loop is utterly pointless. You're replicating using more code what a simple `$array[] = $row;` would do already.

Answer (score 0):

`mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)` should be `mysqli_fetch_array($query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)`. That should be the source of the problem. The while loop is fine for that, but you probably don't need a while and a foreach loop.

Comment: Could you explain why? The manual for mysqli_fetch_array says 'By using the MYSQLI_ASSOC constant this function will behave identically to the mysqli_fetch_assoc()', so the two should be functionally identical.

Comment: Yeah but it was MYSQL not MYSQLI. I forgot the caps though.

Comment: Oh, very well spotted!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't actually define $i = 0. I feel so stupid now... Thanks to Mark Baker for pointing that out, and everyone else for the help!